# About software licenses

Tags: c++, c

Good afternoon, I have a doubt about software licenses, Example if I create a script owner in the editor, eg Notepad + +, Netbeans. He will be an owner or I'll have to make available the source code for free? Because they are licensed under the GPL? Or this license is valid for only the source-code editor, and not to code created with this editor?I would be very grateful for the help.

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#CanIUseGPLToolsForNF

Answer (score 1):

No, your software is not a derived work from the editor or IDE.

It could be something else if you are using parts of the editor in your program - this is the reason the license of `gcc` and similar tools include an exception for this.

Answer (score 0):

No.  In general, the license applies to the editor and the source for the editor.  Consult your attourney.